# Finding an item in list of tuples according to more than one value in Python

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list of tuples, and want to know if a specific item is in the list according to a subset of the tuple's values.
One can us a list comprehension, and check its length (like in the following example), but I want directly to check if the item exists or not.
In the following example, I have a list of tuples, each one has 3 items, and I'm trying to find if an item with the values '1' and '2' for the first two values exists in the list. I don't care about the third value.

```
if len([1 for x, y, _ in tuple_list if x=='1' and y=='2']) > 0:
    do_something
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found a nice solution for that, using operator.itemgetter:

```
from operator import itemgetter
if ('1', '2') in map(itemgetter(0,1), tuple_list):
    do_something
```

Comment: I never saw this operator usage before, nice.